# oninput not triggering from self-made on screen keyboard

Tags: javascript, html

I have an on screen keyboard which is created using this code:

```
function handle(value) {
  document.getElementById('searchbar').value += value
}
```

to type into a search box.
I'm trying to get the search box to search whenever the value of the searchbox changes but this

```
<input type='text' id="searchbar" value="" oninput='searching()' />
```

is only using the searching function when i  type using my keyboard and not the onscreen keyboard.
Thanks

Comment: add `searching();` at the end of your `handle` function.

Comment: because JavaScript does not trigger events.

Comment: oh my god i cant believe i didnt think of that! thank you.